# Distribution Provisioning profile doesn't include development certificate

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

This is status I receive when try to assign Release provisioning profile.

> Provisioning profile "My App Distribution" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: MyFirstAnd LastName (RZ76G7WQ8V)".

Why does it happen?

Why does Xcode try to connect my distribution provisioning profile with my development certificate?

Something is wrong, and I do not know what.

[image]

PS. I do not like to use "Automatically manage signing".

Comment: First of all, Distribution profile should be created with Distribution certificate only. Secondly, this error only pops up because you have selected 'iPhone Developer' certificate in build settings, which was not used when you created provision on apple developer portal. Make sure you select correct certificate in Build Settings, or build provision from correct certificate.

Comment: You are master;) in code signing identity there was `ios developer` for Release mode.;)

Comment: So your issue is resolved ?

Comment: Yes, bottle of wine for you;)

Comment: Haha, glad you solved it mate :) (Y)

Comment: You cannot use an iOS developer certificate and profile for release, if "release" means to build for the app store.  You will need to generate an iOS Distribution certificate and profile if you plan on releasing that "release" build in the Apple App Store.

Comment: @NightFury You saved my day! Thank you!